# Sublime Text 3 Special Character Keybinding

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm trying to figure out how to use the 'asterisk' key on my number pad in a keybinding.

This does not work:

```
[{"keys": ["ctrl+*"], "command": "align_tab","args" : {"user_input" : "=/f"}}]
```

I've tried other key combinations with success (ctrl+8, cntrl+9, etc) but for some reason I cannot get the asterisk key to fire the command.  Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the [list of bindable keys](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/key_bindings.html#bindable-keys) in the unofficial docs, you'll find that the keypad `*` key is named `keypad_multiply`. So, your keybinding should look like this:

```json
[
    {"keys": ["ctrl+keypad_multiply"], "command": "align_tab", "args" : {"user_input": "=/f"} }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, moments after I post the question I figure it out.

In order to see the key event associated with each key, type the following into the Sublime console (ctrl+`):

```
sublime.log_input(True)
sublime.log_commands(True)
```

This will show you the character and key events for each key press.  A little experimenting showed me that the numberpad characters are referenced by "keypad_{operator}".

So, to use the asterisk, the proper keybinding is "keypad_multiply".

The solution to my original problem is:

```
"keys": ["ctrl+keypad_multiply"], "command": "align_tab"
```

***EDIT***

OR, you could save yourself a ton of trouble and just follow the link in @MattDMo's answer. :)

For the lazy, here's a list of bindable special keypad characters:

- keypad_period
- keypad_divide
- keypad_multiply
- keypad_minus
- keypad_plus
- keypad_enter